# Using class variable as non-default argument in python

Tags: python, class, variables, default-value

is there a way to keep a private class variable within the class and still use it as the default value to a non-default variable (without defining that value before, outside of the class)?

example:

```
class a:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__variable = 6
    def b(self, value = self.__variable):
        print value
```

Comment: Python does **not** have private class variables. At all. The double underscore you are using does **not** make the variable private, it just does name mangling to avoid name clashes.

Don't use double underscores unless you know why you have to.  ;)

Comment: Great question! (Well, it solved a huge problem I had, so...)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're overthinking the problem:

```
class a:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__variable = 6

    def b(self, value=None):
        if value is None:
            value = self.__variable
        print value
```

Answer (score 4):

1. `self.__variable` is an instance variable, not a class variable.
2. Because default arguments are evaluated at <del>function</del>method definition time, you can't use an instance variable as default argument - at least not directly (the usual trick, defaulting to `None` and adding `if arg is None: arg = real_default` to the function body, does work).
3. Leading double underscores don't mean "private", they mean "name mangling and asking for trouble". If you don't know exactly what I mean, you shouldn't be using this "feature" at all. The intended use is **not** private members - use one underscore for that.

Comment: What, then, **is** the intended use?

Comment: @Karl: Preventing name clashes in subclasses. See e.g. http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers or http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html?highlight=mangling#private-variables (third paragraph).

Comment: i can still access the variables if i use only 1 subscore

Comment: @calccrypto: Yes, of course. Why not? Actually, the reverse is true: you can't - sanely - access `__variable` anywhere outside the definition of the class (due to name mangling). That's why I highly suggest you drop one underscore.

Comment: @calccrypto yes, that's fine. Python is built on the assumption that we're all adults who understand that accessing another class' variables, without explicit permission (from that class' documentation), is naughty. (And even then, instead of just granting permission, we have `property` wrappers now.) If I wanted that level of compile-time checking, I wouldn't be using a dynamically-typed language.

Answer (score 4):

It's worth adding to this that you can create a custom sentinal value that doesn't get used for any other purpose in your code if you want `None` to be in the range of allowable arguments. Without doing this, `value`, `None` can never be returned from `b`.

```
UseDefault = object()

# Python 3? Otherwise, you should inherit from object unless you explicitly
# know otherwise.
class a:    
    def __init__(self):
        self._variable = 6

    def b(self, value=UseDefault):
        if value is UseDefault:
            value = self._variable
        print value
```

Now `None` can be passed to `b` without causing the default to be used.`